# Xcode 4.4 No such file found launching executable

Tags: ios, xcode

Before anyone just assumes what I am saying here, please read what I have to say.

I have read the hundreds of posts on this topic and have tried pretty much all the suggested resolutions, in no particular order:

- Quitting Xcode
- Deleting the derived data folder
- Cleaning the project
- Hard resetting iPhone
- Resetting Mac
- Tried a second iPhone
- Different USB port
- All these in 'special' order
- Checked code signing attributes
- "Validate Settings" returns no problems
- Validation returns no problems

I am stumped when it comes to this. The only thing I can think of is actually resetting my phone, but don't see how this could help when it doesn't work on the second phone either.

Are there any other suggestions, tips, ideas on what could be causing this rather annoying bug?

UPDATE: The exact error:

```
Error launching remote program: No such file or directory (/Users/Username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ProjectName-dnfacjtdklqktcazrpfyupofdryp/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/ProjectName.app/ProjectName).
```

To get the error, I do any combination of the listed steps above, then click Run on "My Device" (an iPhone 4). Application never installs to the phone and Xcode reports the application has finished running then shows the above error.

Comment: Can you update your post with the actual error you are getting, and the process you go through to get that error?

Comment: Added the details above, do not have another Mac.

Comment: And just to be sure, does it run in the Simulator?

Comment: Yes, Simulator will run in any device mode.

Comment: I'm having the same problem.  It all started after I edited the Build Scheme and changed the Build Configuration to Release and then back to Build.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was cause by me accidently changing the "Deployment Target" (ios version) to a version higher than what was on the phone I tried to run the code on.

Change the deployment target to below or equal to the ios software version on your phone.

(this answer wasn't on your list) :)